# Spring boot proguard obfuscated JAR works locally but not on Azure Pipeline

Tags: java, azure, docker, nginx, proguard

I'm having an issue where my obfuscated JAR file works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it using Azure Pipeline, it fails to run, getting 502 bad gateway. I'm using Maven to build and package my project, and then pushing it to a Docker registry.

here is my pipeline details:

```
- task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'entity/pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'install'

          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'common/pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'install'

          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'security/pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'install'

          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'search/pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'install'


          - task: Maven@3
            inputs:
              mavenPomFile: 'backend/pom.xml'
              mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
              jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              publishJUnitResults: true
              testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
              goals: 'package'

          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'registry'
              repository: 'my_repo'
              command: 'buildAndPush'
              Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
              tags: '$(Build.BuildId).development'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'drop'
              publishLocation: 'Container'
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>recon-ui-service</artifactId>
    <name>recon-ui-service</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <description>recon ui service</description>
    <properties>
        <version.infinispan>12.1.7.Final</version.infinispan>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>recon-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
               <!-- <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                </exclusion>-->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cronutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cron-utils</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>recon-security</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>recon-api-search</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>no.api.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!--     <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream</groupId>
                     <artifactId>recon-parent</artifactId>
                     <version>0.0.1</version>
                     <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                             <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
                         </exclusion>
                         <exclusion>
                             <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                             <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                         </exclusion>
                     </exclusions>
                 </dependency>
                 -->

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.20</version>
                        </path>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <!--<source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>-->
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>7.0.0</proguardVersion>
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                    <outjar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</outjar>
                    <proguardInclude>${project.basedir}/proguard.cfg</proguardInclude>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.guardsquare</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.timestreamgroup.reconstream.ui.service.ReconUiServiceApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <delete file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}_proguard_base.jar"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**App was started but endpoints are not accessible**

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checked the output of the Maven 'package' goal to make sure that the obfuscated JAR file is being built correctly.
- Made sure that the obfuscated JAR file is being included in the Docker image.
- Checked if the Docker image is being deployed correctly to the target environment.
- Checked the logs of the deployed application for any error messages or warnings.

None of these steps have helped me to solve the issue.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue or what other troubleshooting steps I could try?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: looks like network problem, check for network configuration of docker and azure side.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having an issue where my obfuscated JAR file works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it using Azure Pipeline, it fails to run, getting 502 bad gateway

Check if the below troubleshooting steps help you to fix the error 502 bad gateway:

1. Make sure your application is up and running.
2. Make sure that the port in which your application is running is exposed so that you can access your application.
3. Also, make sure to include obfuscated JAR while creating docker image.

If you are running your application on any other port, you can configure the port as shown below:

[image]

*I have reproduced your requirement in my environment, and I could access the endpoints of my application as shown below:*

[image]

Comment: I run my app within Kubernetes